# tf.data.experimental.save VS TFRecords

Tags: tensorflow, dataset

I have notice that the method [`tf.data.experimental.save`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/save) (added in r2.3) allows to save a `tf.data.Dataset` to file in just one line of code, which seems extremely convenient. Are there still some benefits in serializing a `tf.data.Dataset` and writing it into a TFRecord ourselves, or is this save function supposed to replace this process?

Answer (score 0):

TFRecord have several benefits especially when using the large datasets. [TFRecord](https://medium.com/mostly-ai/tensorflow-records-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them-c46bc4bbb564) - If you are working with large datasets, using a binary file format for storage of your data can have a significant impact on the performance of your import pipeline and as a consequence on the training time of your model. Binary data takes up less space on disk, takes less time to copy and can be read much more efficiently from disk. This is especially true if your data is stored on spinning disks, due to the much lower read/write performance in comparison with SSDs.

`tf.data.experimental.save` and `tf.data.experimental.load` will be useful if you are not worried about the performance of your import pipeline.

[tf.data.experimental.save](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/save) - The saved dataset is saved in multiple file "shards". By default, the dataset output is divided to shards in a round-robin fashion. The datasets saved through `tf.data.experimental.save` should only be consumed through `tf.data.experimental.load`, which is guaranteed to be backwards compatible.